# Short story about nuclear war and a rock band?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

*I read this short story as a kid 25-30 years ago at a minimum. Details in my description may reflect that time gap. I'm at a loss for the title or author, but I'd like to read it again as an adult.*

**Plot**

The story takes place in the USA, and seems to be contemporaneous to the date of publication, which I *guess* to be in the mid to late 1970s.

The basic plot is that a large government, military, private institution, or possibly even a rogue player wants to popularize the idea of fighting a nuclear war so that people don’t oppose it. In fact, they want people to actually be excited about it and embrace the possibility.

To foster a pro-nuclear war public opinion, an agent of the organization **recruits or forms a rock band**. I think the genre was acid rock or late 1960s psychedelic because the descriptions of the band's imagery and live shows reflects that era’s visual style. I feel like there was a spinning wheel optical illusion that would mesmerize people. I remember they kept playing to bigger crowds as the story progressed. The band becomes immensely popular. They end up shifting public opinion and people began demanding a nuclear war, if I recall right.

Here’s a key part of the story (and the thing that made me most scared as a kid reading it). The phrase **“Do it, do it. Press the button, press the button!”** (or some variant) was either part of the lyrics to a song, or some subliminal messaging hidden in the music, or maybe a chant that the band led the audience in. I know the audience heard it in some way, because they embraced the chant. It all bordered on a mob mentality and I remember being really disturbed that people would be calling for nuclear war.

**Story spoiler with additional clues**

> I think it ended like this. At the height of their popularity, during one of their concerts, they were broadcasting live to a massive TV audience. One of the viewers was a fan of the band, and he also worked in a nuclear missile silo. The music, or chanting, or subliminal messaging made him launch a nuclear missile. I believe the implication was that it started WWIII.

Comment: Nice, detailed question! If you want some guidance on what other stuff you might know would be useful, see [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is "[The Big Flash](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41610)" by Norman Spinrad, also the answer to this old question: [60s short story where band gives concert ending with a nuke detonation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104117/28516)

Here are the last two pages with the chanting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely the story. I am amazed at how fast you answered this question. I've been looking for it for a long while now. I can't believe I even forgot the band's name  - The Four Horsemen!

Comment: How did you locate it so fast, by the way? I've got a few other half-forgotten tales I'd like to find again.

Comment: My tiny brain is largely wasted by detail memories of old sf stories :) Please, ask your other questions, that's what we're here for!

Comment: Something that the rest of you might find amusing: I don't believe I have read that one, but I swear that as I was reading the original post, I was thinking: "Hey, this plot sounds like something Norman Spinrad would write!"